# Using git to compute commited + unstaged LOC changes over 24 hours

Tags: git

The following bash script can compute the LOC change in a git repo in the previous 24 hours:

```
loc_changed() {
    since=${1:-24 hours}
    author=${2:-your_email@gmail.com}
    git log --numstat --pretty="%H" --author="$author" --since="$since" | awk 'NF==3 {plus+=$1; minus+=$2} END {printf("(+%d, -%d) LOC\n", plus, minus)}'
}
```

**Problem:** This command excludes *unstaged* LOC changes. I think it would be useful to add unstaged changes to this LOC count. How does one do this?

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is this: given a repo, how much changed in the past 24 hours (irrespective of whether those changes have been staged or even committed yet)?

Comment: It also excludes *staged* changes, as `git log` looks only at commits. Neither the index contents, nor the work-tree contents, are commits. You can use some of the `git diff` family of commands that compare from or to the index and/or from/to the work-tree (you'll need one command for HEAD-to-index, then one for index-to-work-tree, for instance, to get staged and unstaged), or else make two commits out of index and work-tree. Or, you can make commits out of these. However, if the index contains an in-progress merge, it's not possible to commit it and overly difficult to diff against it.

Comment: It's up to you to decide what to do *and* how to do it, here; Git merely provides some tools. To diff HEAD vs work-tree, bypassing the index entirely, consider using the confusingly-named `git diff-index` plumbing command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with these changes. I'm sure this code can be optimized :)

```
loc_changed() {

    since=${1:-24 hours}
    author=${2:-your_email@gmail.com}

    stagedPlus=$(git log --numstat --pretty="%H" --author="$author" --since="$since" | awk 'NF==3 {plus+=$1} END {print plus}') 

    unstagedPlus=$(git diff  $(git log -1 --pretty="%H" | tail -1) --numstat | awk 'NF==3 {plus+=$1} END {print plus}')

    stagedMinus=$(git log --numstat --pretty="%H" --author="$author" --since="$since" | awk 'NF==3 {minus+=$2} END {print minus}') 

    unstagedMinus=$(git diff  $(git log -1 --pretty="%H" | tail -1) --numstat | awk 'NF==3 {minus+=$2} END {print minus}')

    if [[ -z $unstagedPlus ]]; then
        unstagedPlus=0
    fi
    if [[ -z $unstagedMinus ]]; then
        unstagedMinus=0
    fi

    print "+$(($stagedPlus+$unstagedPlus)), -$(($stagedMinus+$unstagedMinus))"
}
```

The lines you need are related to `diff`, where I get all changes (counted with `numstat`) from the last commit to the current unstaged code.

Comment: This is brilliant. Is there an easy way to change the units displayed by this command from LOC to `+words added, -words removed`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe playing with the `diff` tool you can count the words added/removed, but in terms of code, a single change of a `+` by a `-` could be counted as a word, so the solution would be so tricky.